# The HTTP request echo query parameter was not returned as plain text in the response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webhooks

I am trying to register webHook with my Asp .Net application and get this error:

> The HTTP request echo query parameter was not returned as plain text in the response. Please return the echo parameter to verify that the WebHook is working as expected.

```
function subscribe() {
  var obj = {
    WebHookUri: "http://localhost:15975/api/Temp",
    Secret: "12345678901234567890123456789012",
    Description: "Chill"
  };

  var dsf =  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/webhooks/registrations",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, status) { 
      alert(status); 
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) { 
      alert(errMsg); 
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Although Webhook POST data on your callback uri "`http://localhost:15975/api/Temp`" but you also need to implement a `GET` method at that uri. It is to validate if given uri is valid.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult Post(object data)
  {
       return Ok(new { results = "POST" });
  }

 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
  public HttpResponseMessage Get()
  {
       var allUrlKeyValues = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
       var parmVal = allUrlKeyValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "echo").Value;
       var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
       resp.Content = new StringContent(parmVal, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
       return resp;
  }
```